# Reference Firebase user objects in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to reference user objects in Firestore like a regular document from collection ? I've created a sample of fake users for test in the Authentication section, and I'd like to reference them in a collection.

Their is the reference field :
[image]

The id seems correct, however calling a db.doc() with this reference as a parameter returns an empty document (snapshot.exists returns false).

The database 'users' isn't present in my collections since it is handled by Firestore authentication system, but I was wondering if their was a way to access it, similar to regular documents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up two products in the Firebase platform:

- Firebase Authentication handles user sign-in.

  All information about these users is stored in an internal database,
  that you can only access through the Firebase Authentication APIs.
- Cloud Firestore stores data that you put in it.

Firebase Authentication does not automatically create any user data in Firestore when a user is created. If you want such data in Firestore, you'll have to create it yourself, either in your application code, or [in Cloud Functions in response to the user-created event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation).

Within Cloud Firestore there is no type that is a "reference to a Firebase Authentication user". But if you store user-specific documents in Firestore, you can use its Document Reference type to reference those user-specific documents.

Comment: If you want to create a user document automatically upon creating the account, you can use Cloud Functions for that pretty easily.  https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-offload-client-work-to-cloud-functions-7c420710f07